# Convertir Excel a JSON y cargar un DataTable

Tags: javascript, css, html5, datatables

soy relativamente nuevo en el lenguaje de Java Script, pero estoy intentando modificar unos códigos que conseguí de internet para transformar registros de archivo Excel al formato JSON para después cargarlo a un DataTable, eh realizado muchas pruebas pero aun no lo consigo.

En los videos tutoriales por lo general profundizan en DataTable exportando a Excel y otro tipo de archivo, pero importando registros desde Excel para cargar un DataTable no hay.Por favor necesito su apoyo en esta implementación.

Alcanzo los códigos correspondientes:

```js
let selectedFile;
console.log(window.XLSX);
document.getElementById('input').addEventListener("change", (event) => {
  selectedFile = event.target.files[0];
})

let data = [{
  "name": "jayanth",
  "data": "scd",
  "abc": "sdef"
}]


document.getElementById('button').addEventListener("click", () => {
  XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(data, 'out.xlsx');
  if (selectedFile) {
    let fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.readAsBinaryString(selectedFile);
    fileReader.onload = (event) => {
      let data = event.target.result;
      let workbook = XLSX.read(data, {
        type: "binary"
      });
      console.log(workbook);
      workbook.SheetNames.forEach(sheet => {
        let rowObject = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(workbook.Sheets[sheet]);
        data = rowObject;
        console.log(rowObject);
        document.getElementById("jsondata").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(rowObject, undefined, 4)
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4/jq-3.3.1/dt-1.10.22/datatables.min.js"></script>
<div class="container mt-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <input class="form-control" type="file" id="input" accept=".xls,.xlsx" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" id="button">Convert</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <pre id="jsondata"></pre>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <table id="control" class="display" style="width: 100%;"></table>
</div>
```

Comment: puedes darnos un ejemplo de que contenido tiene tu excel? por cierto.. por que un excel y no un [tag:CSV]?

Comment: El Archivo Excel tiene 7 columnas y 5 registros incluido el encabezado

Answer (score 0):

Puede que usar XLSX.js sea como matar moscas con cañones para tu caso de uso. Yo te recomendaría validar tu flujo partiendo de lo más simple y luego añadir pasos internedios sólo si los necesitas.

Para este ejemplo usé la librería [read-excel-file](https://www.npmjs.com/package/read-excel-file) a la cual puedes pasarle directo el objeto file sin tener que instanciar un objeto FileReader.

Si en tu caso de uso esperas tener que trabajar con planillas de varias hojas, o te aproblema convertir el array de filas para obtener un array de objetos usando el encabezado, puede que igual termines usando XLSX.js, pero espero que el ejemplo te sirva al menos como punto de partida para  probar la transformación de binario a json y el poblamiento del datatable.

```js
document.getElementById('input').addEventListener("change", (event) => {
  selectedFile = event.target.files[0];
  readXlsxFile(selectedFile).then(function(rows) {
    document.querySelector('#jsondata').innerText=JSON.stringify(rows,null,2);
  })

});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/read-excel-file@5.x/bundle/read-excel-file.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-Ez0cGzNzHR1tYAv56860NLspgUGuQw16GiOOp/I2LuTmpSK9xDXlgJz3XN4cnpXWDmkNBKXR/VDMTCnAaEooxA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>
<div class="container ">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <input class="form-control" type="file" id="input" accept=".xls,.xlsx" />
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12" style="border:1px solid #ccc;">
      <pre id="jsondata"></pre>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Por ahora solo estoy probando con un archivo Excel.Xlsx de 7 columnas y 5 filas incluido el encabezado, mas adelante quiero adaptarlo en un Archivo Excel de aprox 10 columnas y 12 mil filas. He modificado el código como indicas y sigue solo generando el JSON, pero no carga el DataTable.

Comment: Me sigue marcando el siguiente error en consola, linea 3 del Archivo index.js: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')

Comment: Tendrás que ver qué diferencia tu ejemplo del mio. ¿La planilla a lo mejor?

Comment: Hola, el código que reenviaste esta incompleto como para poder comparar con el mío